# How send parameters for URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have send parameters for my backend in PHP but i have code and i not send parameters look

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(modelLocator.CaminhoServidor+"AnexoDocumentos_Financeiro/asdas/xml.php");
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            request.data = Remessa;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, RecebeXML);
            loader.load(request);
```

how send 3 parameters this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 'variables' field in the URLRequest object:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.param1 = ...
variables.param2 = ...
variables.param3 = ...
request.data = variables;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, urlLoader_error);
urlLoader.load(request);
```

Also, it's a good idea to define handlers for errors (as shown for IO_ERROR above but also HTTP_STATUS and SECURITY_ERROR)

Comment: Note that urlLoader.dataFormat is to set the format of the data received back from the load request. It is not to set the format of the outgoing data, so you need to change it to whatever type of data your server is sending back.